# How can I index C arrays in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust, ffi

I have a C function returning a pointer:

```
type MYSQL_RES_REF = *mut c_void;
type MYSQL_ROW = *const *const c_char;

#[no_mangle]
extern "C" {
    fn mysql_fetch_row(res: MYSQL_RES_REF) -> MYSQL_ROW;
}

let pointer = mysql_fetch_row(self.res);
let row_p = match pointer {
    p if p == (0 as *const *const c_char) => panic!(),
    p => p,
};

let field: &[u8] = unsafe { ffi::c_str_to_bytes(row_p[i]) };
```

but attempting to index it (the last line) results in an error:

```
error: cannot index a value of type `*const *const i8`
```

I wonder if `std::c_vec` was what I wanted, but [apparently that has been removed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0494-c_str-and-c_vec-stability.md).

Comment: Note that it's not an array, don't confuse pointer and array in C, that not the same thing.

Answer (score 15):

There is an [`offset` method on pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.offset) which can be used as:

```
let new_p = p.offset(i);
```

to get a pointer `i` elements away from the current one. It is not bounds-checked, obviously, so you must ensure it stays within the bounds (or one-past-the-end).

---

There is also an unstable [`offset` intrinsic](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/fn.offset.html).

Comment: Since Rust 1.26.0, [there's also method `add()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.add) for unsigned offsets and [`sub()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.sub) for unsigned negative offsets.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the length of your C array, you can convert the pointer and the length into a Rust slice and then use all the existing support for slices:

```
use libc::size_t; // 0.2.51
use std::slice;

/// Our opaque C type
#[repr(C)]
struct MyCType {
    private: [u8; 0],
}

extern "C" {
    fn get_ptr_and_len(len: *mut size_t) -> *const MyCType;
    fn do_something_with_type(v: *const MyCType);
}

fn ptr_and_len() {
    unsafe {
        let mut len = 0;
        let ptr = get_ptr_and_len(&mut len);

        let slice = slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len);

        // Indexing
        do_something_with_type(&slice[42]);

        // Iteration
        for v in slice {
            do_something_with_type(v);
        }
    }
}
```

See also:

- [What's the Rust idiom to define a field pointing to a C opaque pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315383/155423)
- [How do I initialize an opaque C struct when using Rust FFI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43350167/155423)

Comment: `let mut len = 0;` There is no point to initialize to zero if the value is supposed to be replace by `get_ptr_and_len()`, either the function return an error and `len` is pointless, or the function is broken somehow and so the init is still useless. However that doesn't cost much but in the cast where a function is a lot used it could so what would be the way to tell to Rust the `len` will be initialize ? As it's "only" a integer this *should* be simple. I think

Comment: Also, C can't have `private: [u8; 0],` field so it's maybe a bad exemple.

Comment: @Stargateur that’s how you create an opaque type (thus the link)

Comment: @Stargateur there is no way to specify that FFI code will initialize the length. In pure Rust you would return a tuple of values but that’s not possible with FFI. You could use `mem::uninitialized` but that’s overkill for a type that can be cheaply zeroed.